# How to hide window scrollbar and make scrolling still working

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I want to hide window scrollbar and I used this css style

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

but the problem here is the srcolling is disabled as well !

So, How to hide window scrollbar and make scrolling still working ?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Here is a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xzg6s/)**

It scroll without scrollbar...

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
body{ 
   height : 500px; 
   overflow : scroll;
}
```